# I have a lot of AWS resources in the tag editor

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created my AWS account and got 12 months free plan. Then I went to the teg editor to check all my running services and there were 165 unnecessary running services. Maybe someone had the same problem? Is this ok and I don't have to pay for it?)
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUX3k.png)

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4800344). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K, the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because they exist, does not mean they are running.

Those look like to be the default VPCs that are created by AWS in every region by default for every AWS account.

If you didn't create them, don't worry - you aren't being charged for them.

AWS does not provide any default resources that charge you money.